# How to use Firebase (V8) Email/password Auth to interact with Firebase realtime database

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I am creating a very simple Chrome extension that periodically updates scores taken from the school website to Firebase Database, each user has a JSON containing his data (name, email, scores, etc...)

I stayed at Firebase v8, Because V9 API is modular, not namespaced. It is too complicated for me to implement it with Chrome extension v3

I wonder if this is the proper way to sign in with a username and get his data.

[image]

Firstly, set Database Rules, only accepting read and write permissions if an Auth.uid is logged in:

```html
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      "$uid": {
        ".read": "auth.uid  ===  $uid",
        ".write": "auth.uid ===  $uid"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then, sign in with email, password by firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword():

```js
async function login() {
  e = email.value;
  p = password.value;
  firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(e, p)
    .then((userCredential) => {
      // Signed in
      //var user = userCredential.user;
      // ...


    })
    .catch((error) => {
      var errorCode = error.code;
      var errorMessage = error.message;

    });
}
```

After the user logged in, use firebase.database.ref() to read his name from realtime database (with the path as users/user.ID/his_name), and update the data if necessary.

```js
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
  if (user) {  
      const getUserRef = async (ref) => {
      const user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
      
      var userCP = await firebase.database().ref().child('users').child(user.uid).child(ref);
    
      userCP.on('value', function(snapshot) {    
      return snapshot;//.val(); Don't know why val() is not working
      });
    }

console.log (getUserRef('name')); //Showing name of the logged-in user
  
  });
```

It is working so far as I expected, but I am very new at this, I am not sure if this auth method is secure enough, can one person peek into another's data?

Comment: What's the question here? That's pretty standard way to get user's data from a database after logging in. But you can also store user's displayName in Firebase Auth itself. Checkout the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#get_a_users_profile) for more infromation.

Comment: @Dharmaraj  Should I  check the authentication twice, to make sure the person who logged in is the one who has access to the database? By comparing accessToken obtained from firebase.auth().currentUser and signInWithEmailAndPassword to see if they match each other?

Comment: No that's not required. Your security rules also look correct and users can read/write their own data only.